# Problema con eventos del Mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(".td_fecha").on("mouseenter", function(){
        $(this).children("img").fadeIn();
});

$(".td_fecha").on("mouseout", function(){
        $(this).children("img").fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.td_fecha{
    position: relative;
}

.td_fecha img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Fecha</th>
<th>Movimiento</th>
<th>Cliente</th>
<th>Monto</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="td_fecha">10-01-2022
<img src="https://acqualaguna.com/img/editar.png">
</td>
<td>Abono</td>
<td>Juan</td>
<td>$500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="td_fecha">10-01-2022
<img src="https://acqualaguna.com/img/editar.png">
</td>
<td>Abono</td>
<td>Carlos</td>
<td>$200</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="td_fecha">10-01-2022
<img src="https://acqualaguna.com/img/editar.png">
</td>
<td>Abono</td>
<td>Miguel</td>
<td>$300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="td_fecha">10-01-2022
<img src="https://acqualaguna.com/img/editar.png">
</td>
<td>Abono</td>
<td>Julio</td>
<td>$500</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Estoy haciendo un ejemplo como el que les puse, lo que necesito es que cuando el cursor del mouse entre a una columna `fecha` muestre una imagen y cuando salga de esa columna oculte esa imagen que previamente mostró.

El problema es que al entrar a la columna si muestra la imagen pero al mismo tiempo la oculta y lo que requiero es que solo la oculte cuando salga de dicha columna.

Porque esta haciendo eso y lo como puedo solucionar??

Comment: Puede que tenga que ver con el evento `mouseout` que afecta al elemento y sus hijos. El evento contrario a `mouseenter` sería `mouseleave`.

Comment: @msalinas tiene razón. Si te miras la documentación de `mouseenter` lo explica y además hay un ejemplo del uso de ambas opciones. https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/